# GitLab CI - Shorten variable value

Tags: heroku, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to enable Review Apps for my project with automatic deploy to Heroku for branches. Each deployment should have the following address:

```
https://prefix-<branch-name>.herokuapp.com
```

Heroku requires app names to be no longer than 30 characters, so my jobs should shorten the branch name, if it's too long.

I've tried to do this in a common Unix way, like this:

```
variables:
  REVIEW_APP_NAME: "prefix-${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG:0:23}"
```

But it resolved to "prefix-".

I have also found the following solution, which allowed me to use the shortened branch name in the script section. But it still can't be used in environment url parameter. And this leads to app being deployed to Heroku, but doesn't tracked by GitLab at all (no deployment in the Environments list and no action on branch deletion).

```
variables:
  REVIEW_APP_NAME: "prefix-$${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG:0:23}"

before_script:
  - eval export REVIEW_APP_NAME=${REVIEW_APP_NAME}
```

Are there any other ways to achieve proper behavior?

Comment: You shouldn't need the braces in your variables. See https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/README.html#using-the-ci-variables-in-your-job-scripts for more details

Comment: @Rekovni, in cases when you don't need truncating - yes. But if I won't be using braces in my case, the REVIEW_APP_NAME value will be like: `prefix-branch-name:0:23`. Which, obviously, doesn't match my expectations.

Comment: What I mean is that I think it should something like: `REVIEW_APP_NAME: "prefix-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG:0:23"`  and that should give you your `prefix-branch-name:0:23` ? (unless I've misunderstood your question)

Comment: @Rekovni, yeah, seems like there is a misunderstanding. What I want, is not to get a string with numbers at the end, but to have my branch name truncated up to 23 characters.

Comment: I need to solve the exact same problem. @Alexander did you solve your problem? Can you add an answer to this question?

Comment: @ByronSommardahl, unfortunately, I didn't find any solution to this problem yet. It was a student project, though. So we just moved our repository to GitHub and enabled built in Heroku integration to acquire the same functionality.

Comment: apparently this is not possible, see: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/24659

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid issues caused by too long branch names that generate too long `CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG` you may use the `CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG` variable with GitLab CI/CD environments, which is created from the `CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG` but truncated to 24 characters: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html.

> For the URL, you could use `$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG`, but because this value may contain a `/` or other characters that would not be valid in a domain name or URL, use `$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG` instead. The `$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG` variable is guaranteed to be unique.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/#create-a-dynamic-environment

Another option is to prepare the name in a previous (or intermediate) job using scripts of your choice and pass environment variables to another job using environment variables inheritance: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/index.html#pass-an-environment-variable-to-another-job

Answer (score 6):

We use a simple bash script for that purpose:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

out=${1:0:40}
if [[ $out =~ ^.*-$ ]]; then
    out=${out:0:-1}
fi
echo $out
```

The if statement checks that the string does not end with a trailing dash.

We then use our script in the CI like this:

```
[...]
  script:
    - export CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME=$(./infrastructure/utils/shorten_branchname.sh $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME)
[...]
```

For images that use *docker* or *alpine* you need to install bash before:

```
[...]
before_script:
    - apk add --update bash
[...]
```

Comment: kudos to @fsperrle (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1496346/fsperrle) for the script and the CI config!

Comment: Thanks for providing this script. However it does not answer the actually question, which is how can we shorten / truncate the value of `$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG` also for building the dynamic url of our dynamic environment for Review Apps in gitlab. Do have a solution here as well?

Comment: I think it does answer it. You can do anything you want in your bash script and it will be easy to find the correct commands to do so. The main point is you will have to call a script and export the env likely. Thanks for answering my question

Comment: The issue with environment URLs is that they can not use variables exported in the `script` section: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#environmenturl

Comment: What you can do is to write variables into a var.env file and upload it as an artifact (see here: https://github.com/dbvis-ukon/coronavis/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml#L254). Then you can use this as a dotenv artifact (https://github.com/dbvis-ukon/coronavis/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml#L679). This makes the variables available also in your environment section (see few lines above second link). 
There are several constraints for that file (size and number of lines especially): http://mpegx.int-evry.fr/software/help/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.md#artifactsreportsdotenv

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID` instead of `$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG` to build the url.

Answer (score 0):

Default `.pre` step will help to make it available for the whole pipeline/sub-pipeline

```yaml
define-review-app-name:
  stage: .pre
  script: 
   - echo "REVIEW_APP_NAME=prefix-${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG:0:23}" >> variables.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: variables.env

my-job:
  needs: ["define-review-app-name"]
  script:
   - echo "$REVIEW_APP_NAME"
```